# Where can I get the Gecko (layout engine) source?

Tags: gecko

I have done quite a bit of poking around for the [gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko) source but I cannot seem to find it.

I have found the word gecko littered through the firefox source code when I do this:

```
for i in `find .`; do grep -ibH gecko $i; done
```

If anyone knows where I can get the source I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the code in mozilla-central is Gecko.  Gecko isn't a precisely-defined term, though.  The mozilla-central repository also contains code that's not Gecko, including Firefox (in browser/).

A good link for how to get the source is https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial

Comment: I think I did something similar. I got the firefox source but could not find anything that looked really relevant.

Comment: It depends what you're looking for.  My first guess at that would be that you might be interested in the code in dom/, content/, and layout/ directories.

Comment: Hi David, in conclusion, I did not find anything that was specific to gecko.  It seems to me that gecko code/references is sprinked through the firefox code base.  I am not sure where you could find a standalone copy of gecko.

Comment: Gecko is no longer available standalone. Instead the nearest equivalent these days is XULRunner.